# Using TImage inside of My Component

Tags: delphi, custom-component

I am trying to use **Timage** inside of my component but I Receive a compiler Error on line `" Image.Parent:=Self;" as 'incompatible type 'TWinControl' and 'TGasTurbine'`

So 'TGasTurbine is my component Name

here is my Paint procedure. What should I do?

```
Procedure TGasTurbine.Paint;
var
   Image: TImage;
begin
  Inherited;
  Image := TImage.Create(self);
  Image.Parent:=Self;
  Image.Height := 100;
  Image.Width := 100;
  Image.Stretch:=True;
  Image.Picture.LoadFromFile('H:\Component\Automation\Pump.Bmp');
end;
```

Comment: do not use LoadFromFile inside Paint. Paint occurs often and it calls LoadFromFile which is VERY slow (because it involves I/O).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the type of your component? How did you describe its class?
If your control is intended to be a parent for other controls, it must be ancestor of TWinControl.

**Edit:**
TGraphicControl cannot contain other components, cannot own them.
You have to choose - or inherit you class from TWindowControl, or reject internal TImage using, and take care about picture storing and drawing (preferable).
It would be better to describe your scenario of picture using.

And why you create internal component in Paint procedure? Normally it is called many times, under every repainting, and creating new component (BTW, without freeing) again and again - is not a wise approach.

Comment: Base Class that i use is TGraphicControl  and about creating TImage in paint Procedure You are right I just Correct it and move codes to Create Constructor now  but it already raise Error

Answer (score 3):

> incompatible type 'TWinControl' and 'TGasTurbine'

This is telling you that a control's parent must derive from `TWinControl`. And your `TGasTurbine` class does not derive from `TWinControl`.

Whilst you could change the derivation, that would be the wrong solution. You should remove the `TImage` control. You have chosen the wrong way to paint an image in a custom control.

Instead declare a field of type `TBitmap` inside your control.

```
FBitmap: TBitmap;
```

Create and populate it in the constructor:

```
FBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
FBitmap.LoadFromFile(...);
```

Then paint it in your `Paint` method:

```
Canvas.Draw(0, 0, FBitmap);
```

Remember to free the bitmap in the destructor.

You might be better linking the image as a resource rather than an external file.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you even trying to even create TImage component as internal component of your own component?

Instead you should create TBitmap to store the image data and then simply draw that bitmap on your component canvas using StretchDraw http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.StretchDraw

And in case if you need support for other image types you could also use TPicture as internal component instead of TBitmap so you get ability to draw all supported image types that are supported by TImage component which also has TPicture as its internal component.